# Find matching rows in 2D numpy array ok, matching columns in 2D numpy array not ok

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

python 3.6.3 / numpy  1.13.3 / ubuntu 17.10

I'm new to numpy and facing some problems with boolean indexing.
This is my test array:

```
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

I want to get the row with values [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]

```
>>> np.all(b==( 5,  6,  7,  8,  9), axis=1)
array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

and it works, row with index 1 matches.

Now I want to get the column with value [4,9,14,29] and I try with:

```
>>> np.all(b==( 4,  9,  14,  19), axis=0)
False
```

but the result is not the expected one (at least by me), since my hope is to get a boolean array such as:

```
array([False, False, False, False, True], dtype=bool)
```

telling me that there is a matching column with index 4.

What's wrong in my guessing?

Answer (score 0):

`np.all` tests whether all array along a given axis evaluate to true, so when you do your second comparison, it first compares the second array with all rows of the 2d array and sets them true or false according to if they equal.

After that, it checks if all array (which are boolean) along given axis (which is column axis in case of 0) now evaluate to true which they don't (as original 2d array row size and passed array's size don't match so everything is false) and hence `np.all` also returns false.

Try this

```
np.all(b.T==( 4,  9,  14,  19), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using *arrays* to do this. And keeping in mind the correct dimensions:

```
In [17]: col = np.array(( 4,  9,  14,  19)).reshape(-1, 1)

In [18]: b == col
Out[18]:
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

And then:

```
In [22]: (b == col).all(axis=0)
Out[22]: array([False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```